# Prevent ASP.NET from encoding strings on output

Tags: asp.net, encoding

How can I stop ASP.Net from encoding anchor tags in List Items when the page renders?

I have a collection of objects. Each object has a link property. I did a foreach and tried to output the links in a BulletedList, but ASP encoded all the links.

Any idea? Thanks!

Here's the offending snippet of code. When the user picks a specialty, I use the SelectedIndexChange event to clear and add links to the BulletedList:

```
if (SpecialtyList.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        PhysicianLinks.Items.Clear();

        foreach (Physician doc in docs)
        {
            if (doc.Specialties.Contains(SpecialtyList.SelectedValue))
            {
                PhysicianLinks.Items.Add(new ListItem("<a href=\"" + doc.Link + "\">" + doc.FullName + "</a>"));    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Midhat God forbids you to down-vote or vote to close...?!

Comment: @Midhat I've added a snippet, but I thought it was pretty clear. Sorry!

Comment: PhysicianLinks in a BulletedList control. SpecialtyList is a dropdown control. Physician is just a custom class I created that contains a doctor's full name, specialties and URL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the Bulletedlist with a repeater

Instead of `PhysicianLinks.Items.Add(new ListItem("<a href=\"" + doc.Link + "\">" + doc.FullName + "</a>"));` , add doc.Link to a List Object and use it to bind the repeater. You can include any html you want in the repeater itemtemplate

Something like

```
List<string> docLinks=new List<string>();
    if (SpecialtyList.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {


            foreach (Physician doc in docs)
            {
                if (doc.Specialties.Contains(SpecialtyList.SelectedValue))
                {
                  docLinks.add(doc.Link) ;
               }
            }
            Repeater1.DataSource=docLinks;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }
```

And In ASPX

```
<ul>
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <li><a href="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString()%>"><%# Container.DataItem.ToString()%></a></li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give us an example... the object's exact type/value and what is being rendered to HTML.

If you're talking about ASP.NET changing `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;` ... you can sometimes get around this sort of thing by using the ASCII code version instead of the HTML shortcut: `&#38;`