# Stop ASP.NET web control from HTML encoding output > Specifically, list items in a bulleted list

Tags: asp.net, html-encode

I have an ASP.NET bulleted list control that is html encoding the list items.

`<strong>First Name</strong> is required and must consist of letters only.`

Is not resulting in "First Name" being output in bold text.

How do I stop the bulleted list control from html encoding its list item output?

The line in the web form is:
`<asp:BulletedList ID="bltUserDetailsErrors" runat="server"></asp:BulletedList>`

Then there's an intermediate list of error messages:

```
userDetailsMessageList.Add(
                "<strong>First Name</strong>is required, must contain only letters, " +
                "and be no more than 50 letters.");
```

Which are then added to the bulleted list:

```
bltUserDetailsErrors.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string message in userDetailsMessageList)
            {
                bltUserDetailsErrors.Items.Add(new ListItem(message));
            }
```

Yes, it's definitely html encoding the output.

`<li>&lt;strong&gt;First Name&lt;/strong&gt;is required, must contain only letters, and be no more than 50 letters.</li>`

How do you get the bulleted list to render the `<strong></strong>` tags so that the text is bolded in the browser.

Comment: What? Can you post an image and how your code is being generated?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode.aspx

Comment: _"Is not resulting in "First Name" being output in bold text"_ But it does, `First Name` is bold, the rest not.

Comment: So are you getting the text "<strong>First Name</strong>" in your bulleted list?  Or or "First Name" but not bolded?  The first would be the result of HTML encoding, the second may be a style problem.

Comment: You can use a repeater as a workaround.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813746/prevent-asp-net-from-encoding-strings-on-output