# Formatting C# Bulleted List like Facebooks comments

Tags: c#, javascript, css, asp.net

I have a requirement where I need to display comments on a web page much like Facebook does (at least formatted as such). I am returning 3 things: User who posted comment, the actual comment, and date posted.

I have everything working fine. I'm getting all the right information from my database and i'm printing it to the screen using an asp Butteted List. I'm starting to believe that this is the incorrect way to do something like this. Ideally, I'd just like to use JavaScript and CSS to format everything but it's all returned in a `div` with list items.

So right now, my return is this:

*User Name comments.... 7/3/2001 05:45:02 PM*

I want it to print as: 

*User Name 

  comments... 

7/3/2001 05:45:02 PM*

**Here is my c#:**

```
        List<String> theComments = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 2);
        List<String> theUser = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 0);
        List<String> theDate = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 3);


        if (theComments.Count >= 0)
        {


            for (var i = 0; i < theComments.Count; i++)
            {

                commentsList.Items.Add(theUser[i] + "\n" + theComments[i] + "\n" + theDate[i]);
            }
        }
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
<div id="commentsArea">
    <span class="style1">Comments</span><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="501px" 
        Height="50px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnPostComment" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Post.png" onclick="btnPostComment_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:BulletedList ID="commentsList" runat="server" Font-Names="Calibri" Style="text-align: center" Width="501px">
    </asp:BulletedList>
</div>
```

I have tried using `Environment.NewLine` and `\n` but no luck. I am using CSS to `word-wrap` which helps, but still doesn't format it correct. Am I going down the right path? I appreciate any helpful advice

Comment: Instead of three lists of strings, can you get one List of `Comments`? Then you could use a repeater (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6weyd81h%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and bind to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get a consolidated list of `Comments`, wrong tool for the job basically.

I'd recomend an [ASP.net repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6weyd81h%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="comments">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <div class="user"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "User") %></div>                                                
            <div class="comment"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment") %></div>
            <div class="date"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date") %></div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You'll need to adjust "User", "Comment" & "Date", dpending on the `Comment` object.

**C#**

```
List<Comment> comments = //Get Comments List
//Maybe: Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath);

rptComments.DataSource = comments;
rptComments.DataBind();
```

**Plan B** if you cant get a consolidated list.

Use HTML as a control by adding an ID and `runat=server`

**ASPX**

```
<ul id="lstComments" runat="server">
    <li id="lstTemplate" runat="server" visible="false">
        <div class="user">{0}</div>
        <div class="comment">{1}</div>
        <div class="date">{2}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**C#**

```
List<String> theComments = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 2);
List<String> theUser = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 0);
List<String> theDate = Fetcher.getImageComments(commentsConnectionString, imagePath, 3);

string template = lstTemplate.InnerHtml;
StringBuilder innerItems = new StringBuilder();

if (theComments.Count >= 0)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < theComments.Count; i++)
   {
      innerItems.AppendFormat(template, theUser[i], theComment[i], theDate[i]);
   }

   lstComments.InnerHtml = innerItems.ToString();

}
```

Maker sure you have `using System.Text` as part of your using statements, this is required for `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jon. Very good instruction and you did a thorough job of explaining both approaches (plan a and plan b). This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

**First thought**

Initially, I thought you could force a line break by using a br or put p inside your li:

```
commentsList.Items.Add("<p>" + theUser[i] + "</p><p>" + theComments[i] + "</p><p>" + theDate[i] + "</p>");
```

or

```
commentsList.Items.Add(theUser[i] + "<br/>" + theComments[i] + "<br/>" + theDate[i]);
```

In first case, a line break will be added before the text and after. In the second, a line break will be added after text.

The best though would be to have your li contain divs:

```
commentsList.Items.Add("<div>" + theUser[i] + "</div><div>" + theComments[i] + "</div><div>" + theDate[i] + "</div>");
```

And then mark that div as [block](http://webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/) div by putting the following in css for your div:

```
display:block
```

This would ideally force div to behave pretty much like a p. Div is preferable because in the future it allows you more control over changing the layout as opposed to p or br.

**BUT - Doesn't work**

However, as you experimented and I found out, the asp:BulletedList encodes the HTML tag, and thus you do not get a line break, you instead get encoded html :-)

**Other solutions**

Either do not use a list item, and instead just put in divs for each comment, and format it. Pretty much. This is doable by adding the display property in css on the div and make it list-item:

```
display: list-item;
```

The other would have to be just make bulleted list not encode html. However, ASP.NET treats li to be a single line item and thus encodes the HTML. I searched around, including on StackOverflow, looks like there isn't a workaround for this. So your best bet would be to see if you can use another HTML element instead of the bullet list.

EDIT: I updated to show the actual code based on additional comments so it will provide more clarify on the solution.

Comment: Yea but the `li` is the entire string. The 3 separate components aren't seperate `li`'s

Comment: So you can add br or p or div in the li, can't you?

Comment: I also tried wrapping my return in C# in HTML and it did not work. It just prints the HTML to the string as text.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like this: `commentsList.Items.Add(theUser[i] + "<br>" + theComments[i] + "<br>" + theDate[i]);`

Comment: Basically, replace your \n with <br/> and see what happens.

Comment: Yes. When I do that, the `<br/>` prints to the screen as plain text. It doesn't recognize that it's html.

Comment: I think your best bet is to not use list item. I searched around (you can too), and it seems that list item treats any text as a single line item (I didn't expect it either). If someone knows a workaround, they may come around, however, there is another q on stackoverflow on the same issue, but no response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511463/stop-asp-net-web-control-from-html-encoding-output-specifically-list-items-in

Comment: Thanks for doing research for me. Everything you said makes sense and confirms my theory of "i'm doing it wrong in the first place" Need to rethink the design...